# How to get the default download directory from selenium web driver in python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to download a file access it through Python code. I'm not able to get the default download directory of the chrome.

Comment: manually you can check the default download folder of your browser namely chrome or firefox. I dont see a way to get it via selenium

Comment: actually I wanted it to be common code for windows and linux machines. So I wanted to make sure I get default download directory within code instead of hard-coding.

Comment: Then we can set the default path while initiating the browser... Try to get the system os via java and write an if else case. If windows take this as download path else if this is linux take this as download path

Comment: You can set relative path to file instead of hardcoded absolute path. Try to use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) or [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module